# Ajax calendar and dropdownlist display issue

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ajax calender extender and dropdown placed just below it, problem is in IE whenever calendar control pops up it pops up beneath drop drown. I tried z-index but doesnot works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Humble apologies in advance, but I'm skeptical that the z-index of the calendar is higher than that of the DropDownList, only because that's all I had to do to fix the exact same problem for myself.

In my CSS file, I added the following line:

```
.ajax__calendar_container { z-index:1000; }
```

To prove any other skeptics wrong, can you tell us what is the z-index of both your calendar container and your DropDownList?

Also, have you installed the [IE Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en)? (It's similar to Firebug in some respects.) That will help you find ALL the CSS properties of your DropDownList and other controls, even if left unchanged at their default values. And if it really isn't the z-index, the toolbar could lead you better down the road to highlighting the real problem.

Comment: @CMMaung, you edit looks useful, but it probably should just be an answer in its own right, rather than editing @David's post.

Answer (score 0):

Is the calendar in a DIV? If so, I think putting it in an iFrame would fix that.

Edit: [this](http://www.javascriptjunkie.com/?p=5) should do the trick