# Combobox shows up in IE6 when a grey background image is used for the page

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

I am facing this queer problem: what i am trying to achieve is like on page load one pop-up would be shown where users need to do something to get the page going, a grey image background is applied to the body to keep the page inactive. But in ie6 the comboboxes of the page shows active and user can select values whish is so frustrating. Can we inactivate the comboxes with the help of css.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use two forms for this. Your popup will reside in one form and all other controls will reside in the other. When you click on the button to show popup you can disable the first form.

You can also place an iframe with 100% width and height which will hide the combobox.

The simplest way is to hide the combobox.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224471/iframe-shimming-or-ie6-and-below-select-z-index-bug) article in SO

[How to cover an IE windowed control (Select Box, ActiveX Object, etc.) with a DHTML layer?](http://www.macridesweb.com/oltest/IframeShim.html)

Answer (score 0):

**Stackoverflow Archive**: [Ajax Calendar and Dropdownlist Display Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/715402/ajax-calendar-and-dropdownlist-display-issue)

If you're dealing with ASP, I recall this very strange issue. It had something to do with how the controls were drawn, and not merely their z-index if I'm not mistaken. I remember having to actually hide the controls when I launched my popup, and show them again when the popup closes.

Seems like [a lot of people](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=dropdownlist+z-index&aq=f&oq=&aqi=) share your pain.

Answer (score 0):

We had that problem before.

An ugly work-arround is to hide all combos when you are going to show the popUp. And show them back when you are closing it.

Using JS it won't be hard (by changing CSS to display:none)